# ElasticSearch.net 6.0.2 : Not able to declare PostData or Index method

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch.net

I have upgraded from Elastic 5.6 to 6.0.2 in .net code.

In 5.6 version below piece of code used to work properly
          List results = new List();

```
     foreach (var result in results)
     {

        var b = new Elasticsearch.Net.PostData<SiteSearchResult>(result);
     }

    public class SiteSearchResults
    {
        public SiteSearchResults() { }

         public int Total { get; set; }

        public List<SiteSearchResult> Results {get;set;}

     }
```

After upgrading to 6.0.2 ElasticSearch.net same code was giving compilation error. 
After checking the definition of PostData I found that it has been changed to

```
   protected internal PostData(IEnumerable<object> item);
```

So I changed my code as below

```
     var b = new Elasticsearch.Net.PostData<SiteSearchResults>(results);
```

But it is giving me error that method is not accessible due to its protection level. I understand that I wont be able to access it directly but I am short of ideas of how to access it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PostData.Serializable(results)`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/post-data.html)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Comment: @Sushil if you need to post newline separate json for e.g. a bulk request, you can use `PostData.MultiJson(results)`